# Split list information coming from tornado web-service

Tags: android, python, web-services, tornado

I have a Tornado web service that returns a list to an android application as below

```
output = []
output.append(img_URL)
output.append(temp_folder_name)

self.finish(output)
```

First it assigns values to a list called "output" and then return it.

My question is how can I split this data within the Android application, I have the following two lines of code within the Android application

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String transformedImageURL = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
```

but when I try to output it (using Toast) the android application force closes. Could you please suggest me a better solution for this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The data between python and android will not full translate well unless you use a message passing convention. I would suggest rolling this data into lets say into JSON. Like this

```
   output = []
   output.append(img_URL)
   output.append(temp_folder_name)
   self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
   from json import dumps
   self.finish(dumps(output))
```

On android side of things, you can use [JSON library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) to parse data.